# Is there a way to control how dark the screen gets when it dims?

Tags: android

Is there a way to programmatically set how dark the screen gets when it dims ? I would like to get it as dark as possible without turning it off and locking it.

It could be a setting in the device as long as I can set it via code like how I can set the screen timeout for example:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 60000);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Programmatically for your app in particular?  Or via some setting for the phone?  If it is the latter, it belongs on android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Through code, I'll make the question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can dim it on timeout:

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, someIntValue);
```

and

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = (float) (someIntValue/ 255.0);
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

you need to override onUserInteraction() to reset back to regular value for screen brightness.

Comment: Might need extend base Android activity for this to work on each Activity page.